# Is it better to keep a context reference when i'm initializing my canvas objects

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is it better to keep a context reference when i'm initializing my canvas objects..

```
var Obj1 = 
{
    Init: function(ctx)
    {
        this.Ctx = ctx;
    },

    Draw: function()
    {
        this.Ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
    }
};
```

Or is it better to pass the context for use each call?

```
var Obj2 = 
{
    Init: function()
    {

    },

    Draw: function(ctx)
    {
        ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height);
    }
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass the context for each call. ( tho none gonna make any performance difference )

Comment: @siam Care to explain why he should do this?

Comment: just a personal opinion hence, commented. if I would've cared  then must've posted as an answer.w/ explanaton :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the context is a global variable their a a small time penalty for accessing it as Javascript must search the prototype tree to find it. In that case and if the function uses it more than twice then passing it can improve the performance.

If you have it as a property of an object there is a small (very small) time penalty if you then pass it, rather than access it via `this.`

You can also close over it

```
const myObject = (function(){
    var ctx; // as closure variable
    return {
        init(){
           ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        },
        drawSomething(){
           ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
        }
    }
}());
```

Which on some implementations of Javascript is the quickest but again that difference is very small and only becomes a factor depending on how often it is used and how much code there is between usage.

In the end it is personal style, and usage that will determine how you access such variable/properties.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want to draw them always to same context or not. If not pass context on each call. If it will be same then keep reference.